# Find matrix $B$, such that $\ker(B)$ = $\text{im}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, how can I find a matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$ such that $\ker(B) = \text{im}(A)$?

[This method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1566459/285446) would probably work, applying a transformation matrix to change to the standard basis, afterwards. However, if $m < n$ and $\ker(A) = \{ 0 \}$, this approach shouldn't work. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $A$ is rank $r$. Taking the SVD with singular values ordered from largest to smallest write $A=U \Sigma_A V^T$. Here I am taking the convention that $\Sigma_A$ is a $n \times m$ diagonal matrix.

The first $r$ columns of $U$ form a basis for the range of $A$. Write $U= (U_1 \ U_2)$ where $U_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$ so that the columns of $U_1$ form a basis for the range of $A$. Then set 
$$
B= W \Sigma_B 
\begin{pmatrix}
U_2^T\\
U_1^T
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\Sigma_B$ is an $n \times n$ and diagonal and its last $r$ diagonal entries are equal to zero, and the  other diagonal entries are nonzero and where $W$ is any one-to-one matrix. Then the kernel of $B$ is equal to the kernel of 
$$\Sigma_B 
\begin{pmatrix}
U_2^T\\
U_1^T
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which you can show is equal to the range of $A$. In particular, any column of $U_1$ is in the kernel of $B$, and any column of $U_2$ is orthogonal to the kernel of $B$.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is similar to the approach I just used, using the complete QR decomposition.

Comment: Surely one can do this without invoking any (singular value or other) decomposition, just by using Gaussian elimination.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible in general.

Consider any $3 \times 1$ matrix $A$. Now you are asking for an $1 \times 3$ matrix $B$ such that ker$(B)$ = im$(A)$. In particular, the kernel of $B$ should be 1-dimensional. But that is impossible, since the rank of $B$ is at most 1, and therefore due to the rank-nullity theorem, the kernel of $B$ has dimension at least 2.

Comment: In my counterexample $m < n$ holds. Do you mean you are interested in $n < m$? In that case Eric's answer works. Note that if $A$ has full rank $n$, then it is simple: $B = 0$.

Comment: Okay, now I think I found the error in my thinking. The matrix $B$ does not have to be confined to $m \times n$. I just need a matrix for which the kernel equals the image of a given one.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy, provided that $\def\rk{\operatorname{rk}}k\geq n-\rk A$ (but if $k<n-\rk A$ it is impossible , since $\rk B\leq k$ and by rank nullity $n=\dim(\ker(B))+\rk B=\rk A+\rk B$ which can be at most $\rk A+k<n$).

Assuming that, we want to find $B$ such that $BA=0$, in other words, each of the $k$ rows of $B$ describes a linear form $\def\R{\Bbb R}\R^n\to\R$ that vanishes on $\def\Im{\operatorname{Im}}\Im A$, and which rows span the space of all such linear forms. Transposing the equation  $BA=0$ gives $A^t B^t=0$, so the columns of $B^t$ lie in the kernel of (the linear map with matrix) $A^t$, and span that kernel. So one just needs to find a basis of the space of solutions of the homogeneous system $A^t x=0$ for $x\in\R^n$ (which basis has $n-\rk A^t=n-\rk A$ elements, by rank nullity), and take their transposes as rows of $B$. In case $k>n-\rk A$, one can just complete with null rows to attain the required number $k$.